# Ubuntu 18.04 - Dell Laptop Keyboard goes dead

Tags: keyboard, dell, laptop

I ran 16.04 on this Precision 7520 laptop for a while with no problems. Just upgraded to 18.04, and now I periodically see this gray slash icon appear on the screen, and the keyboard becomes inactive. It seems completely random, and happens sometimes when I'm not even touching the computer. I've never seen anything like this on Windows, only Ubuntu.

Any insights into what's causing this would be appreciated.

[dead keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EknRD.jpg)